# removing hexbinplot legend in r

Tags: r, legend

Would you please guide me how I can remove the legend of hexbinplot? I set legend = NULL, however, it does not work.

CODE:

```
hexbinplot(V1 ~ V2, 
           data = magic,
           xbins = 100,
           legend = NULL,
           type = c("g", "r"),
           ylab = 'V1',
           xlab = 'V2',
           colramp=my_colors)
```

Comment: From `?hexbinplot` the help page says *colorkey: logical, whether a legend should be drawn.*, so try `colorkey=FALSE`

Comment: ps: its generally best to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including all packages.

Comment: @user20650, post as answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
hexbinplot(V1 ~ V2, 
           data = magic,
           xbins = 100,
           colorkey = FALSE,
           type = c("g", "r"),
           ylab = 'V1',
           xlab = 'V2',
           colramp=my_colors)
```